# xsd: How to extend a type with an unordered list of elements

Tags: xsd

This is a part of my xml schema

```
<xs:complexType name="Friend">
    <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="phone" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="Coworker">
    <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="phone" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="office" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
```

For better maintainability, I would like to have the shared attributes in an (abstract) super type or something like that. But more important, I want that all elements are unordered and also optional.

Is this possible, and what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One-and-half year after this question and the accepted answer were posted, [XSD 1.1 was published](https://www.w3.org/News/2012#entry-9412). In this version it is possible to specify what the OP asked for because a number of restriction on `xs:all` were lifted. One of them is that it is now possible to extend an `xs:all`.

Using XSD 1.1 you can specify the following:

```xml
<xs:complexType name="Person" abstract="true">
    <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="phone" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="Friend">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="Person">
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:all>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="Coworker">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="Person">
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element name="office" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:all>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

This defines the following types:

- `Person`: an abstract type with optional unordered `name` and `phone` elements;
- `Friend`: extends `Person` adding an optional `address` element to the list of unordered elements;
- `Coworker`: extends `Coworker` adding an optional `office` element to the list of unordered elements.

Note that this solution does not work for every XML processor: even though 8 years have passed since the publication of XSD 1.1, a lot of processors still only support XSD 1.0.

Comment: How to migrate to  XSD 1.1 ?

Comment: Note though that XSD 1.1 is [not available in core java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31889170/411282)

Answer (score 19):

You have to limit yourself a little bit, some of the things you are trying to do are not possible in XML Schema.

Suppose you introduce a complex type called `Person` to be a super-type of `Friend` and `Coworker`. Here are your options:

1. Replace `xs:all` with `xs:sequence`, remove `name` and `phone` from the sub-types, add to the super-type, and add inheritance. Your elements now have to be ordered, but you can make them individually optional. It is **illegal** to use `xs:all` in type hierarchies in XML Schema, because the processor cannot tell where the parent content model stops and the child content model starts.
2. Replace `xs:all` with `<xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">` in both types, and add your inheritance. Then your elements become unordered again, but they may repeat.

So in conclusion: given your type names up there, I would guess that your requirements will not be exactly met. I would go for the first option: insisting on arbitrary element order is often not as useful as it seems.

Comment: I was afraid this would be the case. So (1) it will be.

Comment: Finally!!!  someone has put a small but extremely baffling fragment of the W3C spec (https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#cos-ct-extends) into readable English :-).   Thank you @eepp