# How to validate XML against XSD 1.1 in Java?

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd, xsd-1.1

What is the best way to validate XML files against XML Schema 1.1 in Java?

I took the code from this [tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-javaxmlvalidapi/index.html) and changed the line where it looks up the factory to use XML Schema 1.1 as I have seen in this code example from the [Xerces FAQ](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-pcfp.html#faq-4).

This is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;
import javax.xml.validation.Validator;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class XSDValidator {
    private static void validateFile(File xmlFile, File xsdFile) throws SAXException, IOException
    {
        // 1. Lookup a factory for the W3C XML Schema language
        SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/XML/XMLSchema/v1.1");
        // SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

        // 2. Compile the schema.
        File schemaLocation = xsdFile;
        Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaLocation);

        // 3. Get a validator from the schema.
        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();

        // 4. Parse the document you want to check.
        Source source = new StreamSource(xmlFile);

        // 5. Check the document
        try
        {
            validator.validate(source);
            System.out.println(xmlFile.getName() + " is valid.");
        }
        catch (SAXException ex)
        {
            System.out.println(xmlFile.getName() + " is not valid because ");
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The code throws this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No SchemaFactory that implements the schema language specified by: http://www.w3.org/XML/XMLSchema/v1.1 could be loaded
```

As I see it I have exactly the same imports as the code snippet in the Xerces FAQ. I even tried to add Xerces to my Maven dependencies but that didn't help either.

Cheers :)

Comment: Where `"http://www.w3.org/XML/XMLSchema/v1.1"` came from?

Comment: @PM77-1 http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#langids

Comment: It seems that `javax.xml` uses [`W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/XMLConstants.html#W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI) for this purpose.

Comment: If I use that it's the 1.0 schema.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you can use the JAXP service mechanism to search for an XSD 1.1 processor. Load Saxon or Xerces in the normal way, and then enable XSD 1.1 processing. For Saxon this is done using

```
SchemaFactory.setProperty("http://saxon.sf.net/feature/xsd-version", "1.1")
```

**UPDATE 2021-09-04** In recent Saxon releases, XSD 1.1 is the default, and no special property needs to be set to enable it.

Comment: I meant, use SchemaFactory.newInstance() after putting Xerces or Saxon on the classpath, and/or setting the appropriate system property to determine which processor you want to load.

Comment: Its not working for , i have set class both of both jar.

Comment: Then raise a new question and say exactly what you did and exactly how it failed. We can't help you on the basis of one ungrammatical sentence.

Comment: Does not work for me. Whats the minimum Java/Saxon version I need ? Document test.xml has not been parsed correctly: Property 'http://saxon.sf.net/feature/xsd-version' is not recognized.
Property 'http://saxon.sf.net/feature/xsd-version' is not recognized.
Stacktrace:  .....

Comment: It would be nice to have the full code .. I dont know what is the "normal way" to load Saxon or Xerces and I have to google to figure out how to set the appropiate system properties

Comment: @MichaelKay: For Saxon it's better to use the constant from FeatureKeys to set properties: `SchemaFactory.setProperty(FeatureKeys.XSD_VERSION, "1.1");`

Comment: @MichaelKay: Unfortunately I get the following exception when trying to set the property: `Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: Property 'http://saxon.sf.net/feature/xsd-version' is not recognized.`.

Comment: Please raise a new question and explain exactly what you are doing and how it fails.

Answer (score 19):

Unfortunately, neither the JDK bundled version (as of Java 8) nor the latest official version from maven central (2.11.0) contains XSD 1.1 implementation.

You actually need the `2.11.0-xml-schema-1.1-beta` version of Xerces to able to run the example in the FAQ you have linked.

You may do one of the following.

1. Download the `Xerces2 Java 2.11.0 (XML Schema 1.1) (Beta)` binaries from Xerces website and manually add jars to the classpath (or install locally via Maven). Link: http://xerces.apache.org/mirrors.cgi. You need at least the following:

   ```
   cupv10k-runtime.jar
   org.eclipse.wst.xml.xpath2.processor_1.1.0.jar
   xercesImpl.jar
   xml-apis.jar
   ```
2. Use the following unofficial maven dependency.

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.opengis.cite.xerces</groupId>
       <artifactId>xercesImpl-xsd11</artifactId>
       <version>2.12-beta-r1667115</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

Comment: Thanks alot, finally this seems to be the right .jar  There are comments arrounf on SO which say that xercesImpl / 2.11.0 could be used to validate xsd1.1 , but that seems not to be the case

Comment: That's the way to do it. Also with the release **2.12.0**. Additionally I had to set the `cta-full-xpath-checking` feature in the schemafactory:    
```SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/XML/XMLSchema/v1.1");
schemaFactory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/cta-full-xpath-checking",true);
return schemaFactory;```

Answer (score 2):

After searching for a while, [this tutorial](https://blog.adamretter.org.uk/xerces-xsd11-maven/) contains these dependency worked for me:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.exist-db.thirdparty.xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.0</version>
    <classifier>xml-schema-1.1</classifier>
</dependency>

<!-- xpath2 and java-cup are needed at runtime
        for xercesImpl Schema 1.1 support -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.exist-db.thirdparty.org.eclipse.wst.xml</groupId>
    <artifactId>xpath2</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.princeton.cup</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-cup</artifactId>
    <version>10k</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Unfortunately, these libraries don't seem to be official. So, use it at your own risk.

Answer (score 1):

There is a generic XML validator that works with XML Schema v1.1, which uses `xercesImpl-xsd11` `2.12-beta-r1667115`. The validator is available [here as a Maven plugin](https://github.com/openjax/xml/tree/master/xml-maven-plugin#xmlvalidate), and [here as an embeddable library](https://github.com/openjax/xml/blob/master/sax/src/main/java/org/openjax/xml/sax/Validator.java).

Comment: Both links are broken and lead to a 404 not found site.

Comment: @thehandofNOD, apologies for the broken links. I have updated my post. The artifacts for this validator will be released to Maven Central next week (week of 2019-05-06).

Answer (score 0):

Xerces-J provides a "fully compliant XML Schema 1.1 implementation" since version 2.12.0, current version is 2.12.2, see release history here: https://xerces.apache.org/news.html.