# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No SchemaFactory that implements the schema language specified by: http://www.w3.org/XML/XMLSchema/v1.1

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xsd-1.1

```
String language = "http://www.w3.org/XML/XMLSchema/v1.1";SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(language);
```

Please, anyone helps me. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

### XSD 1.1

Stock JDK does not support XSD 1.1.  You'll need either Saxon or Xerces for that.  See [How to validate XML against XSD 1.1 in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20807066/290085)

### XSD 1.0

If XSD 1.0 support is sufficient, you can change

```
String language = "http://www.w3.org/XML/XMLSchema/v1.1";
SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(language);
```

to

```
SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
```